# Adding enemies to game based on value of score

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a beginner and have needed a lot of help to get this far. I'm trying to add more enemies when my score reaches certain values such as 10, 20, etc. Ive tried something along the lines of if score_value >= 10: `num_of_enemies = num_of_enemies + 10` but have been failing to produce results. I feel like it should be simple but i am missing how to add values to this list.

```
import pygame
import random
import math

from pygame import mixer

# initialize game
pygame.init()

# create screen, set height and weight (())
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# Background
background = pygame.image.load('background1.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(background)

# Background sound
mixer.music.load('troubador.wav')
mixer.music.play(-1)

# Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Beasts of Cthulu")
icon = pygame.image.load('knight.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load('wizard.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 500
playerX_change = 0

# Enemy
enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 5
max_enemies = 100

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load('cthulhu.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 735))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(10, 150))
    enemyX_change.append(3)
    enemyY_change.append(40)

# Fireball
# ready - you cannot see fireball on screen
# fire - fireball is currently moving
fireballImg = pygame.image.load('fireball.png')
fireballX = 0
fireballY = 370
fireballX_change = 0
fireballY_change = 8
fireball_state = "ready"

# Score
score_value = 0
previous_score = score_value
font = pygame.font.Font('Enchanted_Land.otf', 32)
textX = 10
textY = 10

# Game over text
over_font = pygame.font.Font('Enchanted_Land.otf', 64)


def show_score(x, y):
    score = font.render("Score :" + str(score_value), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(score, (x, y))


def game_over_text():
    over_text = over_font.render("GAME OVER", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(over_text, (250, 200))


def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))


def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemyImg[i], (x, y))


def fire_fireball(x, y):
    global fireball_state
    fireball_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(fireballImg, (x + 16, y + 10))


def isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, fireballX, fireballY):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemyX - fireballX, 2) + (math.pow(enemyY - fireballY, 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False

    # Game Loop


running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # Background image
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # Keyboard actions
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -4
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 4
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if fireball_state == "ready":
                    fireball_Sound = mixer.Sound('fireball-1.wav')
                    fireball_Sound.play()
                    fireballX = playerX
                    fire_fireball(fireballX, fireballY)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

    # checking for boundaries
    playerX += playerX_change
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736

    # Fireball movement
    if fireballY <= 0:
        fireballY = 480
        fireball_state = "ready"

    if fireball_state == "fire":
        fire_fireball(fireballX, fireballY)
        fireballY -= fireballY_change


    # Enemy movement
    enemyX += enemyX_change

    for i in range(num_of_enemies):

        # Game Over
        if enemyY[1] > 370:
            for j in range(num_of_enemies):
                enemyY[j] = 2000
            game_over_text()
            break
        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
        if enemyX[i] <= 0:
            enemyX_change[i] = 3
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
        elif enemyX[i] >= 736:
            enemyX_change[i] = -3
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]



        # Collision
        collision = isCollision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], fireballX, fireballY)
        if collision:
            explosion_Sound = mixer.Sound('fireball-explosion.wav')
            explosion_Sound.play()
            fireballY = 480
            fireball_state = "ready"
            score_value += 1
            enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 735)
            enemyY[i] = random.randint(10, 150)

        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)




    player(playerX, playerY)
    show_score(textX, textY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: `enemyX` is a list. So what is `enemyX += enemyX_change` supposed to do? You can remove this line of code, because you do `enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]` in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a lot of code and we can't run it, because we don't have the assets. What you need is a threshold, which increases once it was reached.

You can implement it like this:

```
import random

threshold = 10
score = 0
while score < 1000:
    score += random.randint(1,4)  # wherever points come from
    print (f"Score {score}")
    if score > threshold:
        print (f"You have more than {threshold}. Adding enemies ...")
        threshold += 10
```

See how the score can increase but enemies will only be added every 10 points and it needn't hit the value exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of @ThomasWeller is nice (+1). However, you will have difficulty adding it to your code.

Write a function that adds an enemy and use the function in the loop that creates the initial enemies:

```py
enemySurf = pygame.image.load('cthulhu.png')

def addNewEnemy():
    enemyImg.append(enemySurf)
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 735))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(10, 150))
    enemyX_change.append(3)
    enemyY_change.append(40)

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
   addNewEnemy()
```

Use the idea of @ThomasWeller and add a new enemy when the scooter reaches a certain threshold:

```py
threshold = 10

running = True
while running:

    if score_value >= threshold:
        addNewEnemy()
        num_of_enemies += 1
        threshold += 10
        print(len(enemyX))

    # [...]
```